# List of hours and minutes calculate total hours and minutes

Tags: php, codeigniter

Is there any way to calculate total number of the hours and minutes in php;

I have

```
$hours = array(
    'abc' => '02:30','def' => '02:40','efg' => '01:32'
);
```

the value am getting 02:30 m calculating the start time and end time and getting the minutes and converting into minutes means if 2 hours then it is giving in 240.

Need to calculate the number of the hours and minutes using php.

I done using explode them in ":" and add the hours and in minutes if it's is greater than 60 then add 1 to hours, but it's there is bug in the code while creating reports in excel sheet and not showing the proper time.

At last while showing the data using date('H:i',mktime(0,240));

Comment: i read this question now 5 times - and i'm absolutely unable to understand what you want... why should 2 hours be 240 ? and whats your desired result based on your given array?

Comment: i'm not seeing the association either...

Answer (score 0):

Try the `strtotime()` function as:

```
$time = strtotime('2:30');
```

It will return you the timestamp which can be used to add them separately.

Answer (score 0):

Instead using `mktime()` and `date()` it is easier (and more reliable) to format minutes and hours yourself:

```
$items = array(
    'abc' => '02:30','def' => '02:40','efg' => '01:32'
);

$minutes = 0;
foreach ($items as $item) {
    [$hour, $minute] = explode(':', $item, 2);
    $minutes += 60 * $hour + $minute;
}

return str_pad(floor($minutes / 60), 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT) 
    . ':' . str_pad($minutes % 60, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

`date()` and `mktime()` will fail for ranges larger than 24 hours and may be unpredictable when DTS is involved.